# Increase Text Editor Width in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter

When using Jupyter to edit text files, I find the text window too narrow. Is there a way to increase its width? I'm running a theme that gives wider cells in Jupyter notebook, but it doesn't have any effect on the text files. I assume that one has to change some CSS option?

(I had thought that changing the width of the text editor required a different solution than changing the width of the cells (as I currently had full screen cells in my notebooks but a much narrower text editor), but the answer at the duplicate question does work for the text editor as well).

Comment: please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech what would you like to see more of in the question?

Comment: If you can include the code you are using that would be preferable. Se [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note: Looking further into Jupyter notebook I think you might be asking this question on the wrong Stack site.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes/blob/master/jupyterthemes/styles/compiled/onedork.css) is a link to the current CSS file I'm using, but it's a couple thousand lines of code. I don't know enough CSS to pull out the relevant bits, but it has, e.g., `#notebook-container {
 width: 980px;
}` (and several other instances of setting widths). None of this seems to effect the width of the text editor, so I'm looking for anybody who would know the appropriate lines to add for that.